# get values from href link in jquery

Tags: jquery, href

i am trying to get value from a location href link and was able to get the location href link through jquery and i used

```
   var loc =$(location).attr('href');
```

using this i got the value

```
   localhost/example.com/buy.php?ev=product_search&type=sb&search=sony&cat=3
```

now hot to get value of type , search and cat from this link ?

for eg

```
      type=sb
      search=sony
      cat=3
```

my full code

```
 $("input:radio[name=type_radio]").click(function() {
 var loc =$(location).attr('href');

var value = $(this).val();
var type="condition";
alert(loc);
var dataString="value="+ value + "&type=" + type;
   $('.srchcntntagn').css('display','block');
     $('.by-product-list').addClass('opfxsc');
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "modules/buy&sell/load_search.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,

  success: function(html){
  $('.by-product-list').removeClass('opfxsc');
  $('.by-product-list').html(html).fadeIn('slow');
  $('.srchcntntagn').css('display','none');
 }
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this "gup" funciton found here: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

You just add the function to your script then do something like:

```
var type = gup( 'type' );
```

This also eliminates the need for grabbing the URL with the .attr('href') call.

The function itself is:

```
function gup( name )
{
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
 var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
 if( results == null )
  return "";
else
 return results[1];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't only eliminate the need to use `.attr('href')`.  It actually prevents you from being able to use those values with this function.  The `gup` function only extracts the data from the location that is in the browser at that moment.  The OP is talking about manipulating a URL that was extracted from the page's content.

Comment: It's a super useful function - don't get me wrong!  The problem is that it simple does not address the question or aid in solving it.  It might be a correct answer to a different question - but not on this specific question :)

Comment: @Lix We clearly have read this question differently, the OP seems to be asking how to read the value of type from the URL string. If that is their goal my answer is correct. Their question is: "now hot to get value of type , search and cat from this link ?" (hot = how, I am assuming). The current top answer is acheiving the same goal as mine, albeit differently, no?

Comment: yes i want to get those values but i am already using a click function how can use this function and pass values to my click function or some other way out

Comment: $('someElement').click(function(){ var type="gup('type');});

Comment: omg who down voted this man. damn . this works like a charm . awesome regex . i wish i could learn some regex , thanks @ ALL for helping out and thank u  for providing such a awesome regex code

Comment: i wish i could have more up voting power then once . hehehe thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`location.search` will provide you with the query string of a url (including the ?).

You can strip the ? and split the string into arrays on `&`

```
var queries = location.search.substr(1).split('&');
```

If you are working with a string that *isn't* the current URL, try:

```
var queries = some_url_string.split('?')[1].split('&');
```

Either will give you an array like so:

```
['type=sb','search=sony','cat=3']
```

You can then split each element again on `=` to get key/value pairs:

```
for(i=0;i<queries.length;i++) {
  queries[i] = queries[i].split('=');
}
```

Which will give you:

```
[['type','sb'],['search','sony'],['cat','3']]
```

Alternatively, create a query object:

```
var queryObj = {};
for(i=0;i<queries.length;i++) {
  var q = queries[i].split('=');
  queryObj[q[0]] = q[1];
}
```

This will give you an object like so:

```
{
  type: 'sb',
  search: 'sony',
  cat: '3'
}
```

However, if you really need individual variables, you could do:

```
for(i=0;i<queries.length;i++) {
  var q = queries[i].split('=');
  window[q[0]] = q[1];
}
```

This will create variables `type`, `search`, and `cat` in the global scope. **However**, I do not recommend this as you may be overwriting existing variables depending on the querystring you're parsing.

Comment: how to get individual values in form of variables ?

Comment: I have updated my solution to include a method for creating global variables. As I said before, it's not recommended. Is there a reason you can use `test` but not `queryObj.test`? The latter is as much a variable as the former, and you don't need to worry about scope.

Comment: how to get these values into variables such as i can use them to pass on those vales further through ajax .

Comment: @SakshiSharma If your actual question is *"How do I pass URL querystring variables through an AJAX request"*, I suggest you update your question accordingly, because the answer could be different than what is provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and simple -

1. Split the whole url first by a question mark to separate the query from the URL
2. Then another split on the query string using `&`.
3. A further split on each element will spearate the key from the value.

```
var url="localhost/example.com/buy.php?ev=product_search&type=sb&search=sony&cat=3";
var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
var variables = queryString.split('&');
var varObj = {};
$.each(variable,function(index,elem){
  var valueKeyPair = elem.split('=');
  varObj[valueKeyPair[0]] = valueKeyPair[1];
});
```

`varObj` now contains all the info you need.

```
Object
  cat: "3"
  ev: "product_search"
  search: "sony"
  type: "sb"
```

To access the `cat` value for example, all you have to do is use `varObj['cat']`.

Comment: but how to get all of them in a seperate variable such as var cat=3 , ev=product_search etc ?

Comment: For that you might have to use the *evil* `eval()` function.  I don't recommend it at all if you can avoid it.  My solution leaves you with an object who's keys and values match the variables you want.  I think it might be better to use this than have to use `eval()` to dynamically create variable...

Comment: then any method to get each values separation in variables

Comment: @Sak, I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your last comment.  Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: you **could** create global variables with `window[valueKeyPair[0]] = valueKeyPair[1]`, but I would recommend the object solution.

Comment: @sak - Is there any specific reason you don't like the object style of storing variables?  Some other restraint you haven't mentioned perhaps?

Comment: hey i wanted to to get individual values from the link so that i can use ajax and pass those variable further for a search .

Comment: @sak - you can still do that while using an object.  You could simply create a new object with only the parameters you want to send through the AJAX call...

Comment: i see u used a function and i am already using a click function because of which its not working any solution?

Comment: @SakshiSharma if you're trying to send these variables through jQuery's `ajax` function, you probably WANT an object that you can assign directly to the `data` attribute of your `ajax` call. But we can't know that without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you think the problem could be elsewhere, please post some more code so that we can see the context of the problem :)

Comment: the link is from the browser page opened and i get it using jquery and want to break out values from them , m posting my whole code so that it could help .